# Cannot get python3 in Jupyter notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How can I get python3 to run in Jupyter? I cannot get it to supply that kernel as well.
When I run `ipython3 notebook` at the terminal, I check the version of Python:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

where I get the output:

```
3.4.0 (default, Jun 19 2015, 14:20:21) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
```

When I run `jupyter notebook`, I have only the option of a new `python 2` notebook and

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

where I get the output:

```
2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
```

I try to run:

```
sudo ipython3 kernelspec install-self
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | File not found: 'kernelspec'
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem, but solved it by making a virtualenv using Python3 as the Python binary; installed iPython; and launched iPython notebook from virtualenv.  I will test to see if the same procedure works with Jupyter (I expect that it will).  Note that when I did this, I only had the option of making Python 3 notebooks.

The following steps worked for me:

```
mkvirtualenv --python=/full/path/to/python3.5 p35
pip install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

A web page popped up and I was allowed to make a Python 3 notebook.