# Vpython empty scene in Jupyter notebook

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, vpython

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102200/cannot-get-python3-in-jupyter-notebook), but it provides a Linux solution. I'm running Windows 7.  I developed a working Vpython notebook in Jupyter on one machine (in my office). It runs Python 2 (Anaconda package), and it does everything I want it to do.

I have another Windows 7 machine in my classroom. It has Anaconda3, and when I try to run the same notebook file, I get a black, empty scene for the vpython code. Also, if I try to start a New notebook from the Home tab of Jupyter notebook, there is not a VPython selection in the classroom machine.  On my office machine (with Anaconda, Python 2), there is a VPython notebook option in the New list of Home.

I have done `conda update conda` and `conda update anaconda` and `pip install vpython --upgrade` commands on both machines and get the same behavior.

I have tried creating a new notebook with vpython commands and get the same behavior.

Summary: VPython in a Jupyter notebook with Python 2 on Windows 7 works. VPython in a Jupyter notebook with Python 3 on Windows 7 fails.

Any reasonable solutions?